# Mongo shard key distribution if data changes

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We are working on a strategy for sharding a mongo database. Our initial concept involves sharding data based upon user location.

Question is, if a user changes location and the data gets updated, will the user simply be auto-distributed to the appropriate shard?

Comment: To clarify, the data itself has a characteristic/field of "location", this field is part of the shard key, and you are asking if it is allowable that for a given record, can you update the value of "location", which in turn would result in moving the record from one node to another.  Is this correct?

Comment: no they won't be.  the value of the shard key is *immutable* meaning you cannot change it via a normal update.  If you absolutely had to use that as the shard key and if it very rarely could change you would have to write logic in the application that would basically insert the new version of the document in the appropriate place and delete the old version.  Same thing you'd have to do if someone's _id field had to be changed.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, Asya. This answers the question.